# "Include Content" is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

On one of the site collections, when saving a list as list template the "Include Content" checkbox is disabled (greyout). This issue occurs for all lists under all sites. Is this a security feature or is there specific templates that can't include content when saving a list as a list template. I did very that there was no orphan references on the list.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: It is possible that this has been disabled in the List Template if this is a custom list or an Issues List.

Comment: Does this issue only occur for custom list templates? So far I cannot reproduce this issue with all OOTB SharePoint lists...

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with developing a custom list template; Inside of the elements file (Not the elements.xml file for the list definition) under the ListTemplate element I include the DontSaveInTemplate attribute and the set value to True. After deployment, navigated to the list save as template page and verifyed that the include content checkbox is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) on `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SaveAsTemplatePage`, the Include Content checkbox is disabled for the following reasons:

For Lists:

1. [SPList.ExcludeFromTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.excludefromtemplate.aspx) is true
2. Number of items [exceeds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.isthrottled.aspx) the maximum threshold for the Web application

code:

```
if (this.m_ListSel.ExcludeFromTemplate || this.m_ListSel.IsThrottled && !contextWeb.Site.WebApplication.CurrentUserIgnoreThrottle())
{
  this.CbSaveData.Checked = false;
  this.CbSaveData.Enabled = false;
}
```

For Sites:

1. The site is a [Meeting Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/microsoft.sharepoint.meetings.spmeeting.ismeetingworkspaceweb)
2. The [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webtemplateid.aspx) is a [Wiki](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebtemplate.webtemplate.aspx)

code:

```
bool flag = SPMeeting.IsMeetingWorkspaceWeb(contextWeb) || contextWeb.WebTemplateId == 4;
if (flag)
{
  this.CbSaveData.Checked = false;
  this.CbSaveData.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Y
es, 

I


 knew about the 


E


xclude

F


rom




T

emplate property and that the 


M
eeting workspace and 


W



iki site templates. 










































































I


 





I



 didn't know about the threhold limit.