# Move Sharepoint 2010 List to Office365

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I have a Ticket tracking lists I need to move with all the content from SharePoint 2010 foundation to Office365 but I have an issue when I go to the "Save as Template" link the "Include Content" check box is greyed out. How do I enable the check box. I have seen where some people are posting a code fix on other sites but I don't know how to implement that fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Including the content](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Save-a-SharePoint-site-as-a-template-5a4eb024-d1fa-4681-a4ac-e6bd1e3209ba) of the site can increase the size of the template significantly. Keep in mind that the default size limit for a site template is 50 MB but may be less in your organization.

["Include Content" is disabled](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30764/include-content-is-disabled)

I am thinking about two options in this sitution:

**Options # 1:**

Export the List data to excel, then save the list as template(without content). move the list template to O365 and then import the data from excel.

**Option # 2**

Use the 3rd party tools i.e Sharegate / Metalogix etc, they offer the free trail and if you have not too much data then trial will work for you.

Comment: I can export to Excel but how do I import to list?

Comment: check this http://www.layer2.de/en/community/FAQs/cloud-connector/Pages/Office-365-Integration-Excel-files-to-cloud.aspx or http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/10422.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of

1. List Content is large - Default limit is 10 MB
2. `ExcludeFromTemplate` property is set to `true`

The standard SharePoint Issues list has this property set to `true` and hence you won't be able to include content. Since this property is read only we can't change it.

Your best option is to use Central Admin Backup feature and do a granular backup of the list.

Note - I am not sure you can migrate content to SharePoint Online using this method. You can use 3rd party tools. Or you can create a C# console application which read on premise issues list and using SP Online WebService insert into SP Online.